# How to insert CSS effect from mouse events in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to copy the **navbar** from **gmail**, the part where it's **"searching for email"** .. So when you click it it gets white with shadow until you click on another site of the site.

**I did with the:** `active` in **CSS**, however the effect does **not stay permanent**, what is **the correct** way to do this kind of effect with css, **using angular 6?**

**CSS**

```
 .form-container { background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); }
 .form-container:active {
     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
                 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

 }
```

**HTML COMPONENT:**

```
  <!-- form search e-mail -->
  <div class="form-container w-50 rounded py-1 mr-5">
    <form action="#" class="form-inline">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between p-0">
        <!-- search-basic e-mail button -->
        <div><button type="button" [id]="buttons[2].id" class="btn bg-transparent pr-0"><img [src]="images[2].src" [alt]="images[2].alt"></button></div>
        <!-- input for search e-mail -->
        <div class="w-100"><input type="text" class="form-control w-100 border-0 bg-transparent" placeholder="Pesquisar e-mail" aria-label="Pesquisar E-mail's" aria-describedby="button-search-email"></div>
        <!-- search-advanced e-mail button -->
        <div><button type="button" [id]="buttons[3].id" class="btn bg-transparent mr-3"><fa-icon [icon]="faCaretDown" size="sm"></fa-icon></button></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**IMAGE:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `(click)` function to the  form-container that sets a variable, use that variable to set a conditional class on the element that you can remove when you want the effect to go away.

```
<div class="form-container w-50 rounded py-1 mr-5"
  (click)="formActive = true" [class.active]="formActive">
  ...
</div>
```

then your css can be

```
 .form-container.active {
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
             0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);

 }
```

Comment: And how do I disable the effect when the user clicks on any other location that is not the form?